# find max values hashmap and unify the others

Tags: android, hashmap

I want to find 10 max values of a hashmap and i want others to be united into a single value called "Altri", in english it means others.

How can I do this?

I tried with `Collections.max(collection)` after defining `Collection collection=map.values()` but it doesn't work. When I debug it, I see it takes one value that it isn't the higher.

Can anyone help me? Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<T, T> map = new TreeMap<T, T>(yourMap);
```

It will give you sorted data. (natural sorting 1,2,3....100)

Then read **last 10 values** from map.

You will get 10 MAX values

or use

```
SortedMap<T,T> instead of Map
```

it will return sorted data

Comment: I can't insert my HashMap between parenthesis

Comment: try this `SortedMap<T,T> instead of Map`

Answer (score 0):

for that you have to iterate over the hashmap like that:

```
Map.Entry<Foo, Bar> maxEntry = null;

    for (Map.Entry<Foo, Bar> entry : map.entrySet())
    {
        if (maxEntry == null || entry.getValue().compareTo(maxEntry.getValue()) > 0)
        {
            maxEntry = entry;
        }
    }
```